# Passing multiple arguments to a function in apply

Tags: r

I have a problem with passing multiple arguments in `apply` to a function. To be specific i have a boolean function of *N* arguments, from *a1* to *aN*, and i want to compute the truth table for a given function. Here is an example, a majority function of 3 arguments

```
majority <- function(a1, a2, a3) {
  (a1 & a2) | (a2 & a3) | (a1 & a3)
}
```

I also generate a table, containing all possible inputs to a function

```
truth <- matrix(nrow = 2^3, ncol = 3+1)
for (i in 1:(2^3)) {
  truth[i, -(3+1)] <- rev(as.numeric(intToBits(i-1)))[-(1:(32-3))]
  # a bit flimsy but thats not the point
}
```

Then I want to populate the last column with values of a given function from the corresponding row of inputs, but the code...

```
apply(truth[, -(3+1)], 1, majority)
```

...returns an error:
`Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "a2" is missing, with no default`

How can I use the apply function to pass multiple arguments to a function? I know that you can use the `do.call` function to pass a list of arguments to a function, but that doesn't seem to work inside an apply.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function as such here:

```
apply(truth[, -(3+1)], 1, function(x) majority(a1 = x[1], a2 = x[2], a3 = x[3]))
```

In the above, think of `x` as a given row of your `truth` matrix. We pass to your majority function `a1 = x[1]`, `a2 = x[2]`, `a3 = x[3]` (the three elements in the row `x`)

Comment: Indeed, but my truth table generator has to work with all sorts of boolean functions with different number of arguments. Unfortunately your solution is not as flexible, i would not be able to do an apply on the function without knowledge of it's arguments. But this solution might fit for small quantities of functions

Comment: @F.Rosty, in that case, it may be beneficial to re-write the `majority` function as a function of the row, i.e. `majority <- function(x) {(x[1] & x[2]) | (x[2] & x[3]) | (x[1] & x[3])}`.

If it is that your `majority` function has the above format for `N` arguments, you could just do it as `majority <- function(x) {sum(x) > 1}` (if there exists at least two elements with a value of 1, then return true)